# Wordpress site loads repeatedly for every one minute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My site worked perfectly till yesterday. I've installed a plugin called Extendons Woocommerce Direct Checkout. After activating the plugin, my site started to reload automatically for every one minute.
Is there any fix for this issue. I'm unable to reach the development team at the moment. Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Turn of the plugin and let dev team look at it when they get arround. Sounds simple enough. You may have plugins that dont play well together. There is a specific stackexchange for wordpress: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. After deactivating the Direct checkout plugin, everything started to work fine but I need a solution for direct checkout. Cart and checkout should be displayed on the same shopping page.

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, you can clone your site into a subdomain for debugging purposes or check into the main site. I highly recommended the subdomain. I use WooCommerce Direct Checkout but can't fetch this kind of problem. You can deactivate plugin Woocommerce Direct Checkout and check issues. If not find issue then deactivate other plugin and check.

Comment: Thank you. After deactivating the Direct checkout plugin, everything started to work fine but I need a solution for direct checkout. Cart and checkout should be displayed on the same shopping page.

Comment: You can install the previous version of WooCommerce Direct Checkout and check the error. download link: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-checkout/advanced/ 
screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1ulbkx4